# Powershell - Iterate through variables dynamically

Tags: powershell, csv

I am importing a CSV file with two records per line, "Name" and "Path".

```
$softwareList = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\NEW_INSTALLER\softwareList.csv
$count = 0..($softwareList.count -1)
foreach($i in $count){
    Write-Host $softwareList[$i].Name,$softwareList[$i].Path
}
```

What I am trying to do is dynamically assign the Name and Path of each record to a `WPFCheckbox` variable based on the `$i` variable. The names for these checkboxes are named something such as `WPFCheckbox0`, `WPFCheckbox1`, `WPFCheckbox2` and so on. These objects have two properties I planned on using, "Command" to store the `$SoftwareList[$i].path` and "Content" to store the `$SoftwareList[$i].Name`

I cannot think of a way to properly loop through these variables and assign the properties from the CSV to the properties on their respective WPFCheckboxes.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Names like `WPFCheckbox0`, `WPFCheckbox1` etc. has the heavy odor of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - how will you know that you have enough checkboxes for each line in the CSV? You should probably create/generate the checkboxes dynamically as well

Answer (score 0):

*Invoke-Expression* is one way, though note Mathias' commented concerns on the overall approach.

Within your foreach loop, you can do something like:

```
invoke-expression "`$WPFCheckbox$i`.Command = $($SoftwareList[$i].Path)"
invoke-expression "`$WPFCheckbox$i`.Content= $($SoftwareList[$i].Name)"
```

The back-tick ` just before the $WPFCheckBox prevents what would be an undefined variable from being immediately evaluated (before the expression is invoked), but the $I is.  This gives you a string with your *$WPFCheckbox1*, to which you then append the property names and values.  The $SoftwareList values are immediately processed into the raw string.

The *Invoke-Expression* then evaluates and executes the entire string as if it were a regular statement.

Here's a stand-alone code snippet to play with:

```
1..3 |% { 
    invoke-expression "`$MyVariable$_` = New-Object PSObject"
    invoke-expression "`$MyVariable$_` | add-member -NotePropertyName Command -NotePropertyValue [String]::Empty"
    invoke-expression "`$MyVariable$_`.Command = 'Path #$_'"
}

$MyVariable1 | Out-String
$MyVariable2 | Out-String
$MyVariable3 | Out-String
```

As a side note (since I can't comment yet on your original question,) creating an array just to act as iterator through the lines of the file is really inefficient.  There are definitely better ways to do that.